# Allow main (gui) thread while doing a task then update table

Tags: c#, multithreading, datagridview, task

I'm using a winform to try to gather online/offline status of every IP on the network, doing so I'm using a ping request, if it replies it marks the IP as online then moves on. Only issue is waiting for up to 255 replies, after it gets all 255 responses I am wanting it to fill a data grid view.

I've managed to get it all to work but only downside is, gui hangs while doing this process, I figured just use a separate thread with the following expression

```
Thread T1 = new Thread(PingHost)
T1.run();
```

PingHost does as the name implies, pings all the hosts and decides if online or offline. Problem is I tried to update the dgv table from the thread, naturally dgv is locked to main thread.

So I tried switching to a Task and just grab the return value and update after everything is finished. Sadly I can't quite get how to get the return value from the task AND have it run on a separate thread.

I've tried googling different methods, but just running in circles at this point, so I humbly come to you guys for assistance

Code of main thread using tasks

```
List<string> everything = new List<string>();

        int i = 0;


        Task<List<string>> task1 = Task<List<string>>.Factory.StartNew(PingHost);
        everything = task1.Result;
        foreach(var item in everything)
        {
            var index = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["IP"].Value = item;
            i++;
        }
```

And this is the thread of my PingHost method

```
bool pingable = false;
        Ping pinger = null;
        int i = 0;

        string ip;
        while (i < 255)
        {
             ip = "192.168.0." + i;
            try
            {
                pinger = new Ping();
                PingReply reply = pinger.Send(ip, 8);
                pingable = reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
            }
            catch (PingException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
                // Discard PingExceptions and return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (pinger != null)
                {
                    pinger.Dispose();
                }
            }
            if (pingable)
            {
                checkedIP.Add(ip + ": ONLINE");
            }
            else
            {
            checkedIP.Add(ip + ": OFFLINE");

            }
            i++;
        }
        return checkedIP;
```

Comment: Using a Task is not enough. You need to use "async/await". Using ".Result" is just blocking and thus not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit overkill, but I just drafted a solution. Basically I created a new Class for pinging with an event that triggers after each Ping returned, this event uses custom `EventArgs` to return the IP that was just pinged and if it is online or not. I then subscribed to that Event in my GUI Thread and just update the GUI. Here's some code:

This is my Pinger class responsible for pinging the actual Computers:

```
class Pinger
{
    public event EventHandler<PingReturnedEventArgs> OnPingReturned;

    public void PingNetwork()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 255; i++)
        {
            string ip = $"192.168.0.{i}";

            Ping ping = new Ping();

            try
            {
                PingReply reply = ping.Send(IPAddress.Parse(ip));
                TriggerEvent(reply?.Address.ToString(), true);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                TriggerEvent(ip, false);
            }
        }
    }

    private void TriggerEvent(string ip, bool online)
    {
        if (OnPingReturned == null) return;

        PingReturnedEventArgs args = new PingReturnedEventArgs(ip, online);
        OnPingReturned(this, args);
    }
}
```

My custom EventArgs:

```
class PingReturnedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Ip { get; private set; }

    public bool Online { get; private set; }

    private PingReturnedEventArgs() { }

    public PingReturnedEventArgs(string ip, bool online)
    {
        Ip = ip;
        Online = online;
    }
}
```

And finally here is how I'm actually using all of this:

```
Pinger pinger = new Pinger();
pinger.OnPingReturned += Your event handler to update the GUI

// I recommend doing it like this so you can stop the Thread at a later time
// Maybe with like a cancel button
Thread pingThread = new Thread(pinger.PingNetwork);
pingThread.Start();
```

The event handler looks like this `private void PingReturnedHandler(object sender, PingReturnedEventArgs args)`

The two main benefits of this are that 1. the GUI Thread remains unblocked, meaning the GUI will still respond to user input and 2. this procedurally (on every ping completion) triggers the event, meaning that if it takes a long time to ping all the PCs you don't have to wait for the entirety to finish before the user sees something

Comment: For some reason while running, PingReturnedEventArgs gets stuck on 192.168.0.8 even if it's only pinging 192.168.0.4

Comment: Can you give me more info?